# Failed to Connecting SSMS to SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I just installed MSSQL 17 evaluation, and I installed SSIS service.
I know SSIS is running

[image]

And I want to access it from SQLServer Management (SSMS) But I cannot find its service from SMSS GUI. What have I done wrong?

This is my 3rd attempt after reinstalling everything from zero.
Does anybody ever experience this? How to solve?

Below pic shows my SSMS GUI, trying to setup connection to Integration Service, but I couldn't find it

[image]

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to use the old deployment method and not SSISDB?

Comment: Also, try selecting integration services from the downdpwn on the connection page instead, and then typing the name of the host (or `.` if it's the local instance).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the below few things ...

1) Use latest SSMS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

2) Also from your screen shot i am not sure if you have choosen the Intgration Services from the SSMS in the server type. Below is what i meant.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could connect using `DATABASE ENGINE` to your local instance `.`

Then using object explorer under Integration Services Catalog you got full overview of deployed projects and environments:

[image]

<sup>Img source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/media/ssis-azure-deploy-run-monitor-tutorial/ssisdb-deploy-project1.png?view=sql-server-2017</sup>